# Регистрация DLL библиотеки

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll

При попытке регистрации библиотеки выдаёт [image: ошибку]

Exeption_Search.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void OnConnect()
{
    // {5994FCF1-EC8C-48CE-9078-3C4DE11FFD4E}
    static const GUID GUID_handler_no_null =
    { 0x5994fcf1, 0xec8c, 0x48ce,{ 0x90, 0x78, 0x3c, 0x4d, 0xe1, 0x1f, 0xfd, 0x4e } };

    MessageBox( NULL,
        L"Пустое значение", 
        0, 
        MB_OK
    );
    std::cout << "handler_no_null";
}
```

dllmain.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

HINSTANCE   g_hInst = NULL;

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

STDAPI DllRegisterServer(void)
{
    return 0;
}
```

В интернете подробного и понятного решения проблемы не нашла.

Comment: А как выглядит таблица импорта? `DllRegisterServer` экспортируется или нет? Какая битность библиотеки и regsrv32?

Comment: Пока мучаюсь с этим, где-то прочитала, что def не нужен, если используется  extern "C" __declspec(dllexport). Это не так?

Comment: Я имел ввиду таблицу *экспорта в самой библиотеке. А так, да, можно без .def файла обойтись.

Comment: Не знала про неё, пока вы не сказали. Попробую разобраться. Думаю, вопросы ещё возникнут. Сразу вопрос в догонку - программа, для которой мне нужна библиотека, пока что её "не видит". Я неправильно указала GUID или это последствия неудачной регистрации?

Comment: Скорее последствия неудачной регистрации.

Answer (score 0):

Макрос STDAPI разворачивается в `extern "C" HRESULT  __stdcall`, т.е. он сам по себе не задает экспорт функции из DLL. Чтобы функция экспортировалась, достаточно добавить `__declspec(dllexport)`, но для regsvr32 это не поможет, так как при __stdcall функция по умолчанию экспортируется с декорированным именем, а regsvr32 ожидает недекорированное. Для экспорта по недекорированному имени можно использовать либо def-файл, либо параметр компоновщика [export](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/export-exports-a-function?view=vs-2017) (который можно задать в коде директивой pragma).

Декорированное имя для функции без аргументов имеет вид `_DllRegisterServer@0` - его легко получить командой `dumpbin /exports`. Тогда код для экспорта DllRegisterServer будет выглядеть так:

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/export:DllRegisterServer=_DllRegisterServer@0")
STDAPI DllRegisterServer(void)
{
    return 0;
}
```